# How to extract words from a sentence in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table : words contains a single column 'sentence' with 3 rows

### Sentence

Good work keep it up !!
All the best.
Bye

Required Output : Each word after a space in a new line.

Good
work
keep
it
up
!!
all
the
best.
bye

Comment: Search for a `split()` function:  Google "sql server split".  There are many implementations available.

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://bit.ly/1LpgeK2